# Position colorbox with a left margin

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I've got a 2-column layout, sidebar on the left (width: 220px), content to the right, fluid width. I want the colorbox-content to appear over the content-area only, so initiated colorbox like that:

```
$('a#colorbox-load').colorbox({top:20, left:220});
```

Problem is: because the colorbox has same width as before, it now cuts the content off on the right side, the content exceeds the viewport. Since i want the colorbox to be responsive, i could not give a hardcoded smaller width to compensate the shift to the right.
What's the approach?

Desired Layout:

```
+------+----------------------------------+
|      |                                  |
|      |  +----------------------------+  |
|      |  |                            |  |
|      |  |                         X  |  |
|      |  |                            |  |
|      |  |                            |  |
|      |  |                            |  |
|      |  |                            |  |
|      |  |                            |  |
|      |  +----------------------------+  |
|      |                                  |
+------+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the content box(Second column) **position: relative**,
and add

```
#colorbox-load {
    position: absolute;/*or relative*/
    top:20,
    left:220,
    width: 300px; /* specify the default size of colourbox */
    max-width:100%;
}
```

**max-width** property will make it responsive if content box width is less than right edge of colour-box, it will force it to resize

Comment: Tnaks Bhavesh, but i couldn't get your suggestion working… i did set up a fiddle, maybe it's easier to clarify what i am missing: http://jsfiddle.net/3m8AV/2/

Comment: By further investigating, i found out, it's probably not possible to achieve what i want without changing colorbox code: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/627#issuecomment-50379494